# Prove that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral, If $(a+b-c)^{a}\cdot (b+c-a)^{b}\cdot (c+a-b)^{c}\geq a^a\cdot b^b\cdot c^c$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, geometric-inequalities, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

> If $a,b,c$ are the sides of a $\triangle ABC\;,$ such that $$\left(1+\frac{b-c}{a}\right)^{a}\left(1+\frac{c-a}{b}\right)^{b}\left(1+\frac{a-b}{c}\right)^{c}\geq 1,$$
>
> then proving $\triangle$ is equilateral.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as $$\left(1+\frac{b-c}{a}\right)^{a}\left(1+\frac{c-a}{b}\right)^{b}\left(1+\frac{a-b}{c}\right)^{c}\geq 1$$

So $$\left(\frac{a+b-c}{a}\right)^{a}\cdot \left(\frac{b+c-a}{b}\right)^{b}\cdot \left(\frac{c+a-b}{c}\right)^{c}\geq 1$$

So $$(a+b-c)^{a}\cdot (b+c-a)^{b}\cdot (c+a-b)^{c}\geq a^a\cdot b^b\cdot c^c$$

Now how can i solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Did you mean inequality hold if and only if equilateral?

Comment: Yes Chug Tak....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove $a^a\cdot b^b\cdot c^c \geq (a+b-c)^{c}\cdot (b+c-a)^{b}\cdot (c+a-b)^{b}$

Let $a+b-c=2z,\ b+c-a=2x,\ a+c-b=2y$. Without losing generality, assume $x \geq y \geq z$. Now, we need prove
$$\prod \left(x+y\right)^{(x+y)} \geq \prod \left(2z\right)^{(x+y)}$$
$$\prod \left(\frac{x+y}{2z}\right)^{(x+y)} \geq 1$$
$$\prod \left(\frac{x+y}{y}\right)^x \left(\frac{x+y}{x}\right)^y \geq 4^{x+y+z}$$
$$\prod \left(\frac{y+x}{2y}\right)^x \left(\frac{x+y}{2x}\right)^y \geq 1$$
Applying Cauchy theorem for left side, 
$$\prod \left(\frac{y+x}{2y}\right)^x \left(\frac{x+y}{2x}\right)^y \geq \prod \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{x/2} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{y/2} = A$$

After simplifying $A$, we get
$$A = \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{x-y}{2}} \left(\frac{y}{z}\right)^{\frac{y-z}{2}} \left(\frac{x}{z}\right)^{\frac{x-z}{2}} \geq 1$$

Hence the given inequality holds iff $a=b=c$.

Comment: Where the first product $\prod \left(\frac{x+y}{2z}\right)^{(x+y) }$ come from?

Comment: Thanks Alex Silva, I hope the fixed version will be better :D

Answer (score 3):

The title's inequality is wrong. I'll prove a reversed inequality.

Let $a=y+z$, $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y$.

Since our inequality does not changed after substitution $a\rightarrow ka$...,

we can assume that $x+y+z=3$.
And we need to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(3-x)\ln\frac{2x}{3-x}\leq0$ or

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(3(x-1)-(3-x)\ln\frac{2x}{3-x}\right)\geq0$, which is true because

$3(x-1)-(3-x)\ln\frac{2x}{3-x}\geq0$ is true for all $x\in(0,3)$.

The equality occurs for $x=y=z=1$.

Thus, $a=b=c$ and we are done!

Maybe you mean the following problem.

> If $a,b,c$ are the sides of a $\triangle ABC\;,$ such that $$\left(1+\frac{b-c}{a}\right)^{a}\left(1+\frac{c-a}{b}\right)^{b}\left(1+\frac{a-b}{c}\right)^{c}\geq 1,$$
>
> then proving $\triangle$ is equilateral.

Let $a+b+c=1$.

Hence, by Jensen $a\ln\left(1+\frac{b-c}{a}\right)\leq\ln\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)=1$.

Thus, $\left(1+\frac{b-c}{a}\right)^{a}\left(1+\frac{c-a}{b}\right)^{b}\left(1+\frac{a-b}{c}\right)^{c}\leq 1$ and with the given we obtain $a=b=c$.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:
Prove: $$\left ( a+ b- c \right )^{a}\left ( b+ c- a \right )^{b}\left ( c+ a- b \right )^{c}\leq a^{a}b^{b}c^{c}$$
By weight power mean:
$$\sqrt[a+ b+ c]{\left ( \frac{a+ b- c}{a} \right )^{a}\left ( \frac{b+ c- a}{b} \right )^{b}\left ( \frac{c+ a- b}{c} \right )^{c}}\leq  \frac{1}{a+ b+ c}\left ( a. \frac{a+ b- c}{a}+ b. \frac{b+ c- a}{b}+ c. \frac{c+ a- b}{c} \right )= 1$$
i.e.